# Upgrading Django 1.11 to 3.X/Python2.7 to 3.7

Tags: python, django

I have a fairly old website running Django 1.11 and Python 2.7. I am not sure why it doesn't seem to be updating.

I upgraded Python3.5 to Python3.7 just now. Deleted the old virtualenv (by deleting app/bin and creating a new virtualenv with virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3 . )

When in the virtualenv, if I do a python -V I get Python 3.7.7. If I run django-admin --version I see 3.0.6.

But when I try to run the server, my Traceback says:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
 41.             response = get_response(request)

So it's still pointing at apparently an old global install? How can I point it to the new version in the virtualenv I've created?

Comment: did you remove the `*.pyc` files (python byte code), and are you sure you activated the virtual environment when running the server?

Comment: try `python3 manage.py runserver` maybe your python path is wrong. did you edit your bash rc at any point?

Comment: I am certain I activated the virtualenv with a source bin/activate before running gunicorn. I deleted *.pyc files in my settings directories, though there are about 30 other directories I need to delete them from. I will start going through and deleting those but it doesn't have an effect so far. I restarted the server and new *.pyc files were not generated.

Comment: @hansTheFranz running that gives me ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'     even though I am in that directory. I don't think I've edited my bash rc at any point, definitely not today.

Comment: `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` what's written in your requirements.txt file? your bash is looking for the modules in the wrong directory. maybe your python path is wrong. check your bash rc file. use `pip3 instead of pip` to install packages to make sure you get the right version.

Comment: @JasonBoyce: you can use `find -iname '*.pyc' -delete` on a linux system to recursively delete the `*.pyc` files.

Comment: pip3 install -r requirements.txt gets me a ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'  I don't see anything in my .bashrc or .profile that point to a python path. is there somewhere else I could look?

Comment: Thanks for the find -iname @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: OK it looks like I figured it out. My /app directory was root-owned, so I was installing things via sudo pip, which was installing everything globally. I CHMOD'ed the app directory to 777, which lets me install locally via pip. Now it's up and recognizing all the other errors in my old models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. I was using sudo to install virtualenv, python and django because the folder in the root directory, /webapps was root owned. Even in virtualenv, sudo is a global installer, and so my installs were going to the main /usr folder, where there were now two django installs, 1.11 in the python2.7 folder, and 3.06 in the python3.7 folder.

I deleted the virtualenv, ran CHMOD 777 on my /webapps folder so my regular account could create a virtualenv without sudo, and could run pip3 without sudo, which installed my software locally and now everything is working.